# Can the opposition parties do anything within the timelimit if the PM refuses to ask the EU for an extension?

Tags: united-kingdom, brexit, law

It's been noted on this site that [even if Parliament passes an extension, Parliament can't ask the EU for an extension directly themselves](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/44160), that [the law covering withholding the asking of Royal Assent for a bill is a bit vague](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/44169), and it's been [reported that Labour won't back a General Election](https://www.telegraph.co.uk/politics/2019/09/04/hypocrite-jeremy-corbyn-rejects-general-election-break-brexit/), if Boris Johnson was to opt to either:

A) Refuse to give the bill for Royal Assent, or

B) Refuse to ask the EU for an extension (even if he passes the bill for Royal Assent)

What, if anything, could the opposition parties do about it within the timelimit, given they have no intention of calling or backing a General Election.

Comment: On a related topic: https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/44285/can-parliament-stop-the-pm-setting-a-ge-date-after-31-october

Comment: Also related: https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/44286/what-forms-of-redress-are-available-if-a-government-decides-to-act-illegally-by

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If that were to be the case, I believe that the only recourse open to the opposition parties would be to call a vote of no confidence in the government, and attempt to form a caretaker government specifically to ask for an extension within the period set out in the the [Fixed Term Parliaments Act 2011](http://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2011/14/section/2/enacted).

In the case of option B, there may also be cause for legal action to be pursued against any and all government ministers who do not take whatever actions are required of them by the version of the Benn bill which becomes an act of parliament.

Answer (score 5):

Another option:

Bring a case to the ECJ that the UK *hasn't* left "in accordance with it's constitutional requirements", and is therefore still in the EU.

Comment: That would be an interesting case - I suspect the line taken would be that the notification of intent to leave was in line with constitutional requirements, and that is what matters, but reading the text of Article 50 it's actually less clear than I believed.

Comment: This would probably not work even if it is heard.

Comment: To point this out -  the UK could avoid the revocation in good faith issue if this were viable

Comment: @Orangesandlemons Yes, it's likely to fail. If the EU informed the court that they'd accept such an extension it's more plausible.